# overloading an operator in C++

Tags: c++, class, overriding

I'm reading about operator overloading in C++,I have read many tutorial documents & Q&A but I can't find my answer.
in the below code:

```
class Box
{
   public:
      // Overload + operator to add two Box objects.
      Box operator+(const Box& b)
      {
         Box box;
         box.length = this->length + b.length;
         box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;
         box.height = this->height + b.height;
         return box;
      }
};

int main( )
{
   Box Box1;
   Box Box2;
   Box Box3;

   // Add two object as follows:
   Box3 = Box1 + Box2;

   return 0;
}
```

as you can see we override + operator for the BOX class.When we call override operator in main function which one of the class instances used as a **argument** (Box1 or Box2 ?) & which one is accessed by **this** ? actually which one called override operator?why we use **&** keyword in argument? WBR.

Comment: "Why we use **&** keyword in argument". The `&` refers to passing by reference. Without it, your program has to make a copy of `Box` just to use the `operator+`. This takes time and memory where there is really no need.

Comment: then is compiler consider the right hand operator as a const Box& b?Am I true?

Comment: yes. If you used the example from Cheer's answer, `a` is left of the + and `b` is right of the `+`. In he example in your question `this` is left of '+' and `b` is right of '+'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand operand is the `this` argument. To avoid this obscurity, and some more practically significant problems, simply define this operator as an ordinary (operator) function outside of the class. However, operators that modify, such as `+=`, are IMO best defined as class members.

---

Definition outside of class:

```
class Box
{
private:
    // Data members, unspecified in the question.

public:
    // Public interface.
};

// Overload + operator to add two Box objects.
auto operator+( Box const& a, Box const& b)
    -> Box
{
    Box result;
    result.length  = a.length + b.length;
    result.breadth = a.breadth + b.breadth;
    result.height  = a.height + b.height;
    return result;
}
```

---

If your data members are not `public` (you don't specify anything about it), then for the above out-of-class approach you need to add a `friend` declaration of the operator function, in the class. E.g.

```
friend auto operator+( Box const& a, Box const& b) -> Box;
```

---

An alternative with almost the same effect as an out-of-class definition, is to define the operator as a `friend` function within the class, like this:

```
class Box
{
private:
    // Data members, unspecified in the question.

public:
    // Public interface.

    friend
    auto operator+( Box const& a, Box const& b)
        -> Box
    {
        Box result;
        result.length  = a.length + b.length;
        result.breadth = a.breadth + b.breadth;
        result.height  = a.height + b.height;
        return result;
    }
};
```

Here you don't need a separate `friend` declaration.

Another difference is that this in-class-defined `friend` function will only be found via Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL), which means that it's not easy to e.g. take its address. I don't know a way to do that. But at least *knowing about* this approach is necessary in order to understand certain idioms such as the Barton Nackman CRTP-based trick for endowing a class with relational operators.

---

Re

> **”** why we use `&` keyword in argument?

… that's just a convention that overall is an optimization, avoiding some needless data copying. For small types, on modern machines, it may however have the opposite effect.

Comment: "just a convention"...there's good reason for it. And while it may not have benefit for small types (ie copying an int vs passing a pointer to an int), I don't have experience of it being less efficient...

Comment: @Assimilater: One main difference is that the return type specification with `auto` can be an unqualified type from the class. Another difference is that in C++14 (I believe it is) and later, it can be omitted for a simple enough function. That's useful for e.g. delegating `begin()` to a wrapped item.

Comment: Yes, in this code `-> Box` can be omitted. But I wouldn't do it. The point of a high level language is to ease the burden for a human reader, and having to look around and deduce the return type is IMHO instead an increase of the burden.

Comment: @Assimilater: It needs a `friend` declaration *if* the members are not `public`. We don't know. It's not specified. Adding a `friend` declaration that isn't needed, would be wrong. I am very sure that your ESP circuit doesn't work better than mine, i.e., you have no insight whatsover into what the OP thought or what his original code was.

Comment: I was going off your example seeming to imply by the comment that data members are private... (also cleaning up my comment flood....)

Comment: Okay, I added a note about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Box operator+(const Box& b)
```

Here, the addition operator is used to add two Box objects and return final Box object. For that an object is passed as an argument whose properties will be accessed using another object. The object(Box1) which will call this operator(+) can be accessed using **this** operator, while the argument which is passed is Box2.

Comment: In same situation is this usual  that first object call overloading & second one is argument?

Comment: Operator overloading can be simply seen as another way of making a function call, where the only difference is that the arguments don't appear inside parenthesis, but instead they surround or are next to characters(+ in our case). The number of arguments depends on whether it is a unary or a binary operator. The single argument is what appears on the right-hand side of the operator for binary operators. Unary operators have no arguments when defined as member functions. The member function is called for the object on the left-hand side of the operator.